# SVM Classifier based on SURF detectors

Tags: java, python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am a college student, obviously i am newbie in Machine learning so please bear with me.

I am implementing a `Java` application that would recognize and classify `Road/Traffic signs` and my major problem is to create and train `SVM` with `SURF` descriptors.

I read a lot and came across many different things when it comes to `SVM` i became even more confused but i will try to clarify what i understood.

FIRST: i know that i must have a dataset that includes `Pos` images(images that have my objects) and `Neg` images(images that don't have my objects) to train `SVM`. I tried to look how it is done in `python` due to the lack of documentation in `Java` and came across this code

```
import numpy as np
dataset = np.loadtxt('./datasetExample.csv', delimiter=",")
```

And it was simple as that, what is `CSV` doing here? where is the images of the dataset? i know that the data has to be represented in numbers like inside the `CSV` file, but where they came from and what it has to do with `SVM`.

SECOND: I found that in almost all resources `SVM` can be trained by two ways `HOG Descriptors` or `BagOfWords` and didn't find the `SURF Descriptor` method(ACTUALLY i am not sure if it is possible.. but my Dr. said it can be done).

THIRD: Since i am classifying traffic signs i need to have more than one class (EX. One for Warning signs, one for Regulatory signs, etc..), and each class of course has sub-classes like in the `Speed limit signs` it includes different types of signs. I came across smth called `Multi-Class SVM` and i really don't know what is that!!

Currently i managed to extract `SURF Descriptors` from a given image using this code.

```
   Mat objectImage = Highgui.imread(signObject, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
   featureDetector.detect(objectImage, objectKeyPoints);
   descriptorExtractor.compute(objectImage, objectKeyPoints, objectDescriptors);
   datasetObjImage.add(objectImage);
   datasetKeyPoints.add(objectKeyPoints);
   datasetDescriptors.add(objectDescriptors);
```

What i was planning to do is to loop over all images of the dataset and extract their descriptors features to train the `SVM`, but i stucked their since i found the dataset is actually doesn't contain images at all....

So please i would appreciate any sort of help or descriptive steps to achieve that or even good resources i can look at.
Thanks

Comment: John, welcome to computer vision, where everything is unclear and nothing is easy. Your post contains two actual questions, and they concern themselves with parsing CSV and none of the tags. I understand you're frustrated. Breathe in, breathe out. Ask. I'm here to help. There is no easy way.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I need guidelines step by step to implement and train `SVM` classifier for `Traffic signs` in `Java`

Comment: SVM requires a stable set of features. SURF produces feature vectors of random lengths every time. You just can't combine the two. Use HOG or Hu moments. Noo easy waaay.

Comment: Fix the question, by the way.

Comment: Could you pls check this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162150/opencv-for-android-training-svm-with-surf-descriptors?rq=1 , i want to make sure that there is no way to train `SVM` with `SURF Descriptors` ?

Comment: It is possible, you need make more research. These return from Google search:https://www.ripublication.com/ijeer16/ijeerv8n1_01.pdf and https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4624384/