# Getting the SVM example of OpenCV to run in Version 3.0.0 with c++

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm, opencv3.0

I tried to run the [SVM example project of the official OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html) but it seemed that the code is outdated for openCV version 3.0.0.

So i adjusted the code with the help of [this stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114065/opencv-3-svm-training) and came up with the following code:

```
// Data for visual representation
    int width = 512, height = 512;
    Mat image = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);

    // Set up training data
    int labels[4] = { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0 };
    Mat labelsMat(4, 1, CV_32S, labels);

    int trainingData[4][2] = { { 501, 10 },{ 255, 10 }, { 501, 255 }, { 10, 501 } };
    Mat trainingDataMat(4, 2, CV_32F, trainingData);

    // Set up SVM's parameters
    Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
    svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
    svm->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);
    svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6));

    Ptr<TrainData> trainData = TrainData::create(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);

    // Train the SVM
    //svm->trainAuto(trainData);
    svm->train(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);

    Vec3b green(0, 255, 0), blue(255, 0, 0), red(0, 0 ,255), yellow(0, 255, 255);
    // Show the decision regions given by the SVM
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
        {
            Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1, 2) << i, j);
            Mat result;
            svm->predict(sampleMat, result);
            float response = result.at<float>(0);
            if (response == 1)
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = green;
            else if (response == -1)
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = blue;
            else if (response == 2)
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = red;
            else if (response == -2)
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = yellow;
            //else return 0;
        }
```

The code is now at least running without exceptions but it is still not working.

When using the `TrainingData::create` method in combination with `svm->trainAuto(trainData)` I just get a black image ( `predict` always returns 0 ).

If I use `svm->train(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat)` I get an image where every pixel has the same color ( `predict` always returns the same value ). With the labels set as above the image will be all blue.

I do not really see what I may have done wrong.

Comment: Also related: [OpenCV unable to set up SVM Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33899407/5008845)

Comment: Thanks alot Miki. I must have overseen the second example. I found my error now. Your first duplicate refers to another example program. But the second related topic you listed is what I was looking for. I'm sorry for not finding it before posting the question.