# Correctly create training matrix for SVM (OpenCV, C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, training-data

I' m trying to create my own SVM classifier, and i stuck at the beginning. I have two sets of data for positive and negative images, and i want to create training matrix, to pass it into SVM. So i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694810/using-opencv-and-svm-with-images) fundamental post, and tried to do as it says:

```
char* path_positive, path_negative;
int numPos, numNeg;
int imageWidth=130;
int imageHeight=160;

numPos= 176;
numNeg= 735;
path_positive= "C:\\SVM\\positive\\";
path_negative= "C:\\SVM\negative\\";

Mat classes(numPos+numNeg, 1, CV_32FC1);
Mat trainingMat(numPos+numNeg, imageWidth*imageHeight, CV_32FC1 );
vector<int> trainingLabels;

for(int file_num=0; file_num < numPos; file_num++)
{
    stringstream ss(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    ss << path_positive << file_num << ".jpg";
    Mat img = imread(ss.str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    int ii = 0; // Current column in training_mat
        for (int i = 0; i<img.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) {
                trainingMat.at<float>(file_num,ii++) = trainingMat.at<uchar>(i,j);
            }
    }
    trainingLabels.push_back(1);
}
```

But when i start this code i got Assertation failderror: 
I know, that i made some stupid mistake, because i'm very new to openCV.
Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**  The error occurs on this :
     trainingMat.at(file_num,ii++) = trainingMat.at(i,j);

Comment: "C:\SVM\negative\\" must be "C:\\SVM\\negative\\" instead

Comment: As you can see, i've got error when try to read from postive folder, so that's not it.

Comment: you probably wanted to put an *img* into your trainingMat. look, what's on the right side ;)

Comment: Change trainingMat.at<float>(file_num,ii++) = trainingMat.at<uchar>(i,j); to trainingMat.at<float>(file_num,ii++) = img.at<uchar>(i,j);

Comment: Exactly! I said, that i probably made stupid mistake! Thanks a lot!