# Can anyone teach me how to implement multiple binary classification for SVM by openCV?

Tags: opencv, svm, libsvm

I have read the article about the following three links

http://answers.opencv.org/question/42623/face-recognition-using-svm/

[using OpenCV and SVM with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694810/using-opencv-and-svm-with-images)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619039/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SIFT-Features-with-O

I have implemented the multi-class for SVM by openCV, but now, I want to implement multiple binary classification for SVM by openCV to solve multi-class problem. However, I have no idea about this. Can anyone teach me? Please. If it's possible, please provide me an example. Thank you.