# c++ OpenCV Turn a Mat into a 1 Dimensional Array

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, mat

I have this `Mat`:

```
Mat testDataMat(386, 2, CV_32FC1, testDataFloat);
```

Which takes in from:

```
float testDataFloat[386][2];
```

But I can't figure out how to turn it into a 1 Dimensional Array.

Any help?

Comment: `float* testData1D = testDataFloat;`

Comment: a value of type "float (*)[2]" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "float *"

Comment: sorry, `float* testData1D = (float*)testDataFloat;`

Comment: wait, do you want to convert the whole 2D array to a 1D array,or only a single column?

Comment: I want to give Detected Features to an SVM to predict with

Comment: so you want to use all `386*2` feature values, my code should be ok. But you have to make sure that the ordering is the same as during training (row- or column-first compared to your 2D array). I can't tell you how data was trained in your task =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample includes:

1. direct method to convert from float 2d array to float 1d array.
2. way to create a cv::Mat from 2D float array
3. way to create 1D float array from a 2D cv::Mat that has no padding (e.g. stepsize = size of a single row)

This one works for me:

```
int main()
{
    const int width = 2;
    const int height = 386;
    float testDataFloat[height][width];

    // create/initialize testdata
    for(unsigned int j=0; j<height; ++j)
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<width; ++i)
        {
            if(j%5 == 0)
                testDataFloat[j][i] = 0.0f;
            else
                testDataFloat[j][i] = 1.0f;
        }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    // Direct convert from 2D array to 1D array:
    float * testData1DDirect = (float*)testDataFloat;



    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    // create Mat with 2D array as input:
    cv::Mat testDataMat(height, width, CV_32FC1, testDataFloat);

    // convert from Mat to 1D array
    // this works only if there is no padding in the matrix.
    float * testData1D = (float*)testDataMat.data;


    // test whether the arrays are correct
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<width*height; ++i)
    {
        if(testData1D[i] != testData1DDirect[i])
            std::cout << "ERROR at position: " << i << std::endl;
    }

    // output the Mat as an image:
    cv::imshow("test", testDataMat);
    cv::waitKey(0);

}
```

Comment: To feed a `Mat` the 1D array, would this be correct?

`Mat testDataMat1D(height, 0, CV_32FC1, testData1D);`

Comment: the 1D array has size `width*height` elements (after conversion, alternatively use `arraySize`), and you can't use `0 cols` in a matrix, so the call should be: `Mat testDataMat1D(height*width, 1, CV_32FC1, testData1D);` ... but you could use the 2D array directly to feed it into the cv::Mat...

Comment: Yeah I meant 1 and not 0, but I didn't think of `height*width` thanks! Anyway, should `testDataMat1D` be legible to be feed into a `SVM.predict`?

Comment: it is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694810/using-opencv-and-svm-with-images and the way I read that, I would say it should be ok for `SVM.predict`, although I dont have any own experience with SVM.

Comment: @MLMLTL no, you cannot use a `Mat` with multiple rows to feed into `predict()`. It requires a single row, multi _column_ `Mat`.

Comment: so like `Mat exampleMat(1, x, CV_32FC1, exampleFloat);` or like `Mat exampleMat(x, 1, CV_32FC1, exampleFloat);` ?