# OpenCV 2.4.11 SVM Prediction from Test Images

Tags: c++, image, opencv, classification, svm

I am currently working on training and testing greyscale images. So far I've trained the images using the `svm.train()` method.

However, I fail at testing the images. So far My Code for Testing the Images:

```
for (int i = 0; i < test_files.size(); i++){
    temporary_image = imread(test_files[i], 0);
    Mat image1d(1, temporary_image.cols, CV_32FC1);
    //Mat row_image = temporary_distance.reshape(1, 1);
    float result = svm.predict(image1d);
    printf("\n%d\n", result);
}
```

Could you please tell me, how can I fix the problem?

`svm.predict(image1d)` --> This gives the error.

Whether I make it `float result = svm.predict(image1d)` or `svm.predict(image1d)` simply same problem occurs.

Before Asking this question I read

[Error on SVM using images](http://answers.opencv.org/question/18032/error-on-svm-using-images/)

[using OpenCV and SVM with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694810/using-opencv-and-svm-with-images)

Comment: `image1d` must be a matrix with one sample per row (so in your case 1 row), and number of columns equal to the size of your descriptor. Do you used in training and testing image with the same size?

Comment: And you usually don't use classifiers directly on the image, but on some features extracted from the image

Comment: @Miki Thanks for the reply! Yes I exactly use training and testing image with the same size. About your 2nd comment, could you please show me how do you do feature extraction from image? of course related with svm.

Comment: Have a look at Bag of (Visual) Words for example, this is too broad for a comment (and even for a single answer :D)

Comment: What error do you have? You probably need to convert your image to CV_32F. You can use `convertTo`